# ToggleMask in primeNg password not working

Tags: angular, passwords, primeng

I try to use passwordModule in my code, which is working fine then I tried to add toggle mask

```
<input id="float-password"
               type="password"
               [toggleMask]="true"
               pPassword />
```

it gives me the following error

```
Can't bind to 'toggleMask' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

I have tried to find the reason and fix, but unfortunately I'm not getting it.

Comment: This error is coming because 'toggleMask' is not declared in the component.

Comment: @VinaySomawat toggleMask is a attribute right? I gave its value directly as true.
pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use component selector instead of the directive, as directive does not contain `toggleMask` ([See here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/2369cb217238d4958af63c2336ccc662605c59ed/src/app/components/password/password.ts#L19)) where as the component does.

Make sure to import `PasswordModule`

```js
import { PasswordModule } from "primeng/password";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    PasswordModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and use it like so

```html
<p-password [toggleMask]="true"></p-password> //Works
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-password-demo-blf94c)

BTW, `pPassword` directive has `showPassword` @Input which can be used to toggle password display

Comment: If I use component selector it gives me error *Can't bind to 'p-password' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.*

Comment: @Syedmohamedaladeen Answer updated, Please create a reproducible stackblitz if issue still occurs